# Tried to encode a column with LabelEncoder, typeerror occurred

Tags: python, scikit-learn, typeerror, encoder

My code:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

lbe = LabelEncoder()
lbe.fit_transform(kat_df["GND_CODE"])
```

Error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

How can I fix it?

Note: this `GND_CODE` column has 2 inputs: `'E'` and `'K'`

Comment: Can you include the full stacktrace of the error as text? This will allow us to see the line number in the library where the error occurred. Ideally, you should also include a minimal set of input data that reproduces the error, so other users can try your code.

Comment: can you tell what is `kat_df` ?

Comment: can you give the complete code that you tried, in error there is a new word '<' that is not in the code